# Backticks work in ruby script when run from command line, but not from Crontab

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cron, backticks

I have a Ruby script with the command

```
`notify-send "Error in EYW Spaces script" "#{Shellwords.escape(message)}"`
```

If I just run the script from the command line, I get the popup message, but if I put the script into the crontab

```
*/5 * * * * ruby ~/software_dev/scripts/new_script.rb
```

then nothing happens. I know for a fact that the script is running correctly, as I'm getting script output emailed to me, but its just that the popup is not appearing.

Any ideas?

Comment: `notify-send` probably isn't in your `PATH` when your script runs from cron. You're better off, in general, not assuming that `PATH` has anything in particular unless your script sets it itself. Maybe your script should use the full path to `notify-send` rather than relying on `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this isn't specifically a ruby issue, but its due to calling notify-send from crontab.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/298608/notify-send-doesnt-work-from-crontab

One solution on there was to add `DISPLAY=:0` to your script:

```
`DISPLAY=:0 notify-send "Error in EYW Spaces script" "#{Shellwords.escape(message)}"`
```

Comment: Funnily enough, this worked for another command that wasn't working
`zenity --info ....`, which now displays when DISPLAY=:0 is set, but notify-send doesn't.

Will have a play with the PATH

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

- The user running the crontab (root, you, ???) and their system permissions
- `ruby` version and `notify-send` in that user's `PATH`
- Not specifying the `DISPLAY` variable in your cron

Try this (change the number to the correct DISPLAY value) -->

```
*/5 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 ruby ~/software_dev/scripts/new_script.rb
```

May be helpful:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display